# How do I poll and schedule a DAG in Apache Airflow?

Tags: cron, airflow-scheduler, airflow

How to schedule a job in Airflow to poll and run every 30 minutes between 1- 3 ?
I am trying it with the following cron syntax for schedule_interval value

- Cron syntax 1: `0 1-3 ***`
- Cron syntax 2: `0 0/5 1,2,3 * * ?`

Will cron syntax 2 work in airflow or any additional code is required to poll the DAG from 1-3 for every 30 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to hours 1-3 or days 1-3 of every month? And do you want to include 03:30?

Assuming hours and including 03:30, this cron will do: [`0,30 1-3 * * *`](https://crontab.guru/#0,30_1-3_*_*_*)

Assuming days of month and including 03:30, this cron will do: [`0,30 * 1-3 * *`](https://crontab.guru/#0,30_*_1-3_*_*)

There are a few cron-expression validators on the internet to check your expression, e.g. https://crontab.guru (there's a button "next" to see the next 5 times).

Or, if you prefer code, you could try [croniter](https://pypi.org/project/croniter/):

```py
from croniter import croniter
from datetime import datetime

base = datetime(2021, 1, 1)
iter = croniter("0,30 1-3 * * *", base)

for _ in range(10):
    print(iter.get_next(datetime))

# 2021-01-01 01:00:00
# 2021-01-01 01:30:00
# 2021-01-01 02:00:00
# 2021-01-01 02:30:00
# 2021-01-01 03:00:00
# 2021-01-01 03:30:00
# 2021-01-02 01:00:00
# 2021-01-02 01:30:00
# 2021-01-02 02:00:00
# 2021-01-02 02:30:00
```

Comment: I want it to run between 1 to 3 everyday. This cron syntax worked: 0,30 1-3 * * *